# How can I be sure OpenGL is working?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm seeing performance issues when running Kerbal Space Program on my Thinkpad T430 (Core i7 2.9 GHz, 8 GB RAM, Intel onboard graphics), and one of the things I've been told to try is running under DirectX or OpenGL.  I know DirectX is Windows specific, but how can I make sure OpenGL is loaded and working?

Ubuntu Mate 16.04.3, 4.10.* kernel, Ubuntu native version of KSP (not Steam or Windows/Wine).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Execute the following command in a Terminal:

```
glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:'
```

If in the result shows `Yes`, then you have 3D acceleration, and hence OpenGL.

If `glxinfo` is not installed in your system, then install it first by executing the following command on a Terminal:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

Here is the output of my terminal installing `mesa-utils` and executing the command I told you before:

```
galoget@hackem:~$ sudo apt install mesa-utils
[sudo] password for galoget: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mesa-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 31,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 125 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 mesa-utils amd64 8.3.0-5 [31,9 kB]
Fetched 31,9 kB in 1s (24,2 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-utils.
(Reading database ... 161837 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mesa-utils_8.3.0-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-utils (8.3.0-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up mesa-utils (8.3.0-5) ...

galoget@hackem:~$ glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:'
direct rendering: Yes
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was quick -- but I can't check it until I'm at home.  I'll come back then...

Comment: Ok, good, let us know what is the result when you get home.

Comment: Got an alarm set to remind me -- should be about three hours.

Comment: `glxinfo` was already installed, and the result was "direct rendering: Yes".  Thanks!

Comment: when runnginn the command above, i got this: Error: unable to open display! Can you help please?

Comment: @mee You can check this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) for that error message,hope it helps.